# import failed on changing project.properties file android

Tags: android

I recently included adMob into my project. It contains a list `Activity` and a main `Activity` that extends `Activity`. I had to change the `project.properties` file to android-13 in the last line to compile against and 13. I'm caught in a fix. If I change the android version to 13, the whole list activity screws up with errors in every line. It has the error message `"cannot import android.os.*"` on the first line. The main activity is fine. If I compile against android-10 which was the original way it was, then i can run it on the emulator but I get the massage to add adActivity with config Changes. Please advice on how to fix the errors in list activity

Comment: Please supply the logcat and code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do u have API13 in your sdk?

android/platforms/(see here)

Comment: You are awesome. But changing the project properties to android-16 worked. But I still get the message "You must have AdActivity declared in your AndroidManifest.xml with config changes with errors" - Not able to see the ads. Help me with this please.

Comment: I'd also like to add that I'm running my application on 2.3.3 device while compiling it with android-16. I also have a Jelly bean device to test. But with the JB, the old activity that's already in the back comes to the forefront. cant really help it.

Comment: case fixed. had to download api level 13 and update the sdk for 16. The ad now works magically

Comment: sorry that i couldnt respond to you as i was out of station for 2 days. Happy that this is solved.